# Are there any pitfalls for making an event handling method static?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, static-methods

I have the following code (from https://github.com/timabell/PageStructureBuilder ) and the ever knowledgeable ReSharper is suggesting that I make the `DataFactoryCreatingPage()` method static.

Is this safe, or would I be introducing a potential fault when used as an event handler?

```
public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
{
    DataFactory.Instance.CreatingPage += DataFactoryCreatingPage;
    DataFactory.Instance.MovedPage += DataFactoryMovedPage;
}

void DataFactoryCreatingPage(object sender, PageEventArgs e)
{
    var parentLink = e.Page.ParentLink;
    var page = e.Page;
    parentLink = GetNewParent(parentLink, page);

    e.Page.ParentLink = parentLink;
}
```

I can't think of any issues, but I'm wondering if I have a gap in my knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: I saw this and it made me even more nervous http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658248.aspx

Comment: As far as I could see all that was saying is if you have a static event handler, the subscriber should unsubscribe before it goes out of scope. Have to remember to do it of course. .Net not as managed as it tries to make out :(

Comment: What happens when another class you don't know about also uses the event and assigns a different ParentLink?  Does it still work if it does so before or after yours?  Event handler execution order is not deterministic.  Don't use an event when you need a virtual method.

Comment: @Hans My guess would be that you have a good point, and it is probably going to go wrong :-)

Comment: The "ever knowledgable ReSharper" indeed. One of the many things I like about ReSharper is the discussion and inquiry that it initiates. It often offers me options about aspects of my code that I dont understand but in following up on them I feel it makes me a relatively better, more knowlegdable developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no reason why that handler should be static; the reason ReSharper suggests to make it static is probably because you're not using any instance variables within its body, so there's no harm, but event handlers shouldn't be static as they should be able to modify/use internal fields of the class that provides the handler's implementation

Comment: Everything referenced inside the method is also static, so it does compile when it is made static.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper would do that if your method only uses the parameters passed in and does not access any member variables.

You dont have to do it.